# update jqCloud with new word list

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm able to use jqcloud (v 2.0.1) successfully in the controller like this:

```
$("#keywords").jQCloud(response.data.wcpings, {width: 500, height: 350})
```

The above code renders the word cloud properly

I've the following code in my angularjs directive (which updates the wordcloud based on an ajax call):

```
$("#keywords").empty();                                      
$("#keywords").jQCloud(response.data.wcpings);
```

I'm getting the new words and there is no change in the backend code which generates these words. I expect to see the word cloud redrawn with new words but i get empty cloud. I also dont see any js errors at all.

Can anybody help?

TIA

Comment: Probably because you are not using DOM correctly, you use `$("#keywords")` while you should not. It might be a problem.

Comment: thanks for reply. The $("#keywords").empty() calls works and clears out existing words though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you have the proper version of JQCloud : as the release note  shows, updating a cloud was only added in 1.0.5 ((https://github.com/mistic100/jQCloud)

Use the update method to dynamically change the list of words in the cloud.

`$('#keywords').jQCloud('update', new_words);`

(taken over from the doc at : http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/)